# SQL query to pivot table on column value

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

This has probably been covered before, but my skill level with SQL is low enough that I'm not even sure how to properly search for what I want!

I think what I want to do is relatively simple, and it seems that using pivoting might be the solution, but I'm really not sure about the syntax for that.

I have a SELECT query which can return data in this format:

```
 TeamID |   PlayerName
--------+-------------------
   1    | Arthur Schiller
   1    | Dimitre Rogatchev
   1    | Mohamed Hechmeh
   1    | Santosh Pradhan
   2    | Adriano Ferrari
   2    | Amanda Compagnone
   2    | Danail Delchev
   2    | David Bergin
```

I want to create columns from the ID with rows filled with the appropriate names, like this:

```
        1         |         2
------------------+-------------------
 Arthur Schiller  | Adriano Ferrari
 Dimitre Rogatchev| Amanda Compagnone
 Mohamed Hechmeh  | Danail Delchev
 Santosh Pradhan  | David Bergin
```

The purpose is to use the returned data in a php mysqli_fetch_assoc call to display the two columns on a website.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately MySQL doesn't support windowing functions to generate a unique value for each of those rows per team. You can create a derived "row number" using variables or you could use a correlated subquery similar to:

```
select 
  max(case when teamid = 1 then playername else '' end) Team1,
  max(case when teamid = 2 then playername else '' end) Team2
from
(
  select TeamId,
    PlayerName,
    (select count(*)
     from yourtable d
     where t.teamId = d.TeamId
       and t.playername <= d.PlayerName) rn
  from yourtable t
) d
group by rn;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79aab4/3).

**Note:** depending on the size of your data you might have some performance issues.  This works great with smaller datasets.

Comment: the only issue I have with this is the correlated subquery... I would have done the same but correlated subqueries can be really really slow..

Comment: Thanks! This is working exactly as I wanted, but I'll spend some time looking into the issue raised by @JohnRuddell as speed is somewhat of a concern for me, which I assume it almost always is with these things!

Comment: @JonEvans think of it this way.. you have a table with only 1000 rows this query would be selecting all 1000 rows for every 1000 rows in the table and doing a comparrison.. which is 1 million comparrisons

Comment: @JohnRuddell I agree that there could be performance issues with large datasets.  I added a note about that.

Comment: @bluefeet thanks for adding that note at the bottom! with that warning its an awesome post :) +1 hopefully reciprocated :)

Answer (score 2):

you cannot do this with a pivot because there is no common ground to pivot off of.. what you can do is make a row count that you join on for the second team.. try this

```
SELECT t.playername as '1', f.playername as '2'
FROM
(   SELECT @a := @a + 1 as id, playername 
    FROM players 
    WHERE teamid = 1
)t
LEFT JOIN 
(   SELECT @b := @b +1 as id , playername 
    FROM players 
    WHERE teamid = 2
)f ON f.id = t.id
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @a :=0, @b :=0)t1
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee3a0e/1)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I've tried that query and it does sort the rows into the correct columns (1 and 2) and the players with TeamID 1 are properly listed under the 1 column, but the 2 column is all NULL.  Did I mess something up with your code?

Comment: @JonEvans I don't know I would have to see the query... look at the demo I put in my answer... if you have an issue please put it up in that demo and see whats up.. i'll be able to look at it there and help

Comment: I see that it's working perfectly on your demo, so I'm going to try and figure out why it's working there and not on my database, as it seems to me they are both setup the same.

Answer (score 1):

This will be much easier to do in the PHP code rather than trying to do it in the SQL. Just perform the query and then loop through the results adding them to an array for each team.

In general SQL is good for storing, associating, indexing and querying.

Massaging it into the right format you need to display is usually easier, cleaner and neater to do in code though.

Comment: I've actually already got it working in PHP as I want it, but I figured this was not the correct way to do this.  Is it considered okay by standard practices to just get the data I want from a query and then sort it through the PHP?

Comment: mysql can handle this operation easily and it would most likely be faster than doing it in PHP